# Grails: Hibernate and Data migrations

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, data-migration

I have a domain class that is for a customer.  I have had to change to domain class recently because we were gathering a billing address and a shipping address, but were only recording one zip code value.  So I thought what a simple fix.  Change zipcode to billzipcode and then create a new field for shipzipcode.  I ran dbm-gorm-diff to create the change log and then ran dbm-update to execute the changes I've made.  Everything to this point works swimmingly.  But then I go to debug the app to see that the changes to datasource were ok.  However, now when I try to save a new customer record it get this error:

```
    NULL not allowed for column "ZIPCODE"; SQL statement:
insert into customer (id, version, billaddr, billcity, billstate, billzipcode, cell, contact, country_id, custcode, custname, date_created, email, fax, last_updated, organization, phone, shipaddr, shipasbill, shipcity, shipstate, shipzipcode, status, tenant_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-164]. Stacktrace follows:
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ZIPCODE"; SQL statement:
insert into customer (id, version, billaddr, billcity, billstate, billzipcode, cell, contact, country_id, custcode, custname, date_created, email, fax, last_updated, organization, phone, shipaddr, shipasbill, shipcity, shipstate, shipzipcode, status, tenant_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-164]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:293)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:680)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:120)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:84)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:73)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:226)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:129)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at com.companyName.appname.billing.CustomerController$_closure6.doCall(CustomerController.groovy:45)
    at grails.plugin.multitenant.core.servlet.CurrentTenantServletFilter.doFilter(CurrentTenantServletFilter.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I'm at a loss because the ZIPCODE column is not longer in the domain class.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
per request here are the changes that were generated by the migrations plugin:

```
changeSet(author: "user (generated)", id: "1363806498118-1") {
    dropColumn(tableName: "admission", columnName: "pen")
    addColumn(tableName: "admission") {
        column(name:"pen_id", type:"bigint")
    }       
}


changeSet(author: "user (generated)", id: "1363806498118-2") {
    addColumn(tableName: "customer") {
        column(name: "billzipcode", type: "varchar(50)") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }
    }
}

changeSet(author: "user (generated)", id: "1363806498118-3") {
    addColumn(tableName: "customer") {
        column(name: "shipzipcode", type: "varchar(50)") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }
    }
}

changeSet(author: "user (generated)", id: "1363806498118-4") {
    addColumn(tableName: "customer_costs") {
        column(name: "subtotal", type: "float(19)") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }
    }
}


changeSet(author: "user (generated)", id: "1363806498118-5") {
    addForeignKeyConstraint(baseColumnNames: "pen_id", baseTableName: "admission", constraintName: "FK1A21809D0C6EF15", deferrable: "false", initiallyDeferred: "false", referencedColumnNames: "id", referencedTableName: "pen", referencesUniqueColumn: "false")
}

changeSet(author: "user (generated)", id: "1363806498118-6") {
    dropColumn(columnName: "zipcode", tableName: "customer")
}
```

Comment: Did you actually look at the schema to make sure there are only those 2 zip codes and it didn't leave the original column around?

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure how to view the schema of the db thats being used for development env.  The datasource is set to -- url = "jdbc:h2:db/dev;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"

Comment: Post your migrations.

Comment: You'll have to look at the underlying schema. Only way that error can occur is if the column exists. Are you sure the migrations were run for development?

Comment: Ok, so even though I don't have an editor to accurately read/look at the schema it does look like the column is still there, and I have to change the setting in datasource.groovy to dbCreate = create-drop. Then fix some of the test data in my bootstrap to replicate those changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice your changeset the entry for billzipcode is actually adding a new column instead of renaming the zipcode column. Because of this you would still have to manage the data migration. Something like this should work in you case:

```
changeSet(author: 'user (generated)', id: '1363806498118-4') {
    comment { 'Renaming zipcode to billzipcode' }
    renameColumn(tableName: 'customer_costs', oldColumnName: 'zipcode', newColumnName: 'billzipcode', columnDataType: 'varchar(50)')
}
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218163/how-do-i-modify-a-column-using-grails-database-migration-plugins-groovy-dsl) a related question and @Burt's accepted answer points to [this](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/blob/master/testapp/price.changelog.groovy) link.